# Is it normal that java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder() accepts String longer than 76 characters?

Tags: java, java-8, base64

I use `java.util.Base64` (introduce in Java8) and its rfc2045 decoder available with `Base64.getMimeDecoder()`. I expected that the decoding of a Base64 encoded String longer than 76 characters would lead to an exception but it seems to work.

```
String value = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
// encode with rfc4648 to have a String longer than 76 chars 
String encoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(value.getBytes()));
System.out.println(encoded.length()); // 84 chars
// decode with rfc2045
String decoded = new String(java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes()));
System.out.println(decoded.equals(value)); // true
```

Is it a bug in the java Base64 implementation of rfc2045 or is it allowed to have Strings longer than 76 chars as input?

Comment: I would think the decode should be liberal about accepting longer strings, but the encoder should attempt to follow the standard as closely as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the RFC2045 the only place in the Base64-section 6.8 that mentions the 76-char-limit states

> The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more
>      than 76 characters each.

So this only mentions encoding.

There is a section concerning decoding in the "Quoted-Printable"-section 6.7 that reads

> (5)   Encoded lines must not be longer than 76 characters,
>             not counting the trailing CRLF. If longer lines are
>             found in incoming, encoded data, a robust
>             implementation might nevertheless decode the lines, and
>             might report the erroneous encoding to the user.

So here decoding of too long lines is explicitly allowed. As 6.8 does not mention decoding at all I think it's fair to adapt the regulation from the previous paragraph.

As an aside note that java's "Mime"-decoder is even more lenient than the "Basic"-decoder since it will ignore non-Base64 characters while the "Basic"-decoder will reject the entire input.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is used at several places, and before [java.util.Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) was introduced there were several sources. The limitation on 76 characters stems from line sizes of 80 characters of punch cards and old monochrome monitors.
The problem which lead to this restriction was that in C one read lines in a fixed size buffer.

As seen from the javadoc link above, for mime encoding a line break still is generated. Decoding needs no such artificial restriction. And one should not wonder that a more lenient decoding is done. It does not reduce quality.